# Parameterize a closed surface.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We are told to find a tangent plane of the surface

$$x^2 +2y^2+3z^2=36$$ at the point $(1,2,3)$.

Is it possible to parameterize this surface in 2 variables, perhaps with a spherical or cylindrical coordinate system?

I attempted to solve it by creating

$$F(x,y,z)=x^2 +2y^2+3z^2-36$$

and noting that the gradient of a function is normal to its surface, and all you need to define a tangent plane is a normal vector and a positional vector and you can denote the plane as
$$r\cdot n=a\cdot n$$
Is this approach correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Go on! The quicker the better, and you are almost done. No need to parametrize, so your title is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\nabla F(1,2,3)=(2,8,18)$, the plane that you're after is
$$
2(x-1)+8(y-2)+18(z-3)=0;
$$
in other words, it's the plane $x+4y+9z=36$.

Answer (score 1):

$\nabla(x^2+2y^2+3z^2) = (2x,4y,6x)$ at $(1,2,3)$ is $(2,8,18)$ and is the normal vector to your tangent plane.

Can you parametierize this plane now?

Comment: but how would you parameterize this surface for future reference?

Comment: The surface of the ellipsoid?  Quasi-spherical coordinates.  $x = 6\cos\theta\sin \phi, y = 3\sqrt 2\sin\theta\sin\phi, z = 2\sqrt 3 \cos\phi$